# mamp pro wordpress virtual hosts

Tags: wordpress, mamp, virtualhost

So I'm using MAMP PRO, to have a better vhost utility. Ok. I've got serious problems with wordpress.

I successfully done this:

1. pointed a vhost reghellin.unbit.it to:
   /Users/stratboy2/Documents/01-LAVORI/perbacco/XHTML/SITO-PERBACCO/
2. Installed wp 3.3.1 multisite here:
   /Users/stratboy2/Documents/01-LAVORI/perbacco/XHTML/SITO-PERBACCO/giboperbacco

ok?

I then:

1. setted up another vhost www.giboperbacco.com to:
   /Users/stratboy2/Documents/01-LAVORI/perbacco/XHTML/test_multisite
2. installed there a normal (for now..) fresh version of wp.

Can't really install it. Every time I go to www.giboperbacco.com, I get redirected to test.unbit.it/giboperbacco

Why?

1 IMPORTAT NOTE: this issue happens only with wordpress. If I substitute wp's index.php under [path]/test_multisite with another index.html or even another .php with no wordpress code, the vhost WORKS FINE.

So I guess it's not really a vhost problem, maybe some kind of wp problem.

2 IMPORTANT NOTE

I also tried to create and point some more vhosts to [path]/test_multisite, but all keep redirecting to test.unbit.it/giboperbacco

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer by myself..

Simply copied a wrong wp_config file that contained mutisite directives that referenced the other path.

:P

Bye!